# ActiveMQ Error Message for Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ with version 5.12.1. When I shut down the server today, I got the error message. I could start the ActiveMQ but I got the same error message when I shut it down. The shutdown worked fine before. Could anyone tell what the message mean? And how I may resolve the problem. Thanks,

```
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /app/actmq/apache-activemq-5.12.1
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /app/actmq/apache-activemq-5.12.1
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: /app/actmq/apache-activemq-5.12.1/conf
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: /app/actmq/apache-activemq-5.12.1/data
Connecting to pid: 11546
INFO: failed to resolve jmxUrl for pid:11546, using default JMX url
Connecting to JMX URL: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute stop task. Reason: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jmxrmi
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute stop task. Reason: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jmxrmi
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShutdownCommand.runTask(ShutdownCommand.java:116)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:62)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractJmxCommand.execute(AbstractJmxCommand.java:387)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:154)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:62)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)
ERROR: java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jmxrmi
java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jmxrmi
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShutdownCommand.runTask(ShutdownCommand.java:117)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:62)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractJmxCommand.execute(AbstractJmxCommand.java:387)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:154)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:62)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jmxrmi
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:370)
        at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:268)
        at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:227)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractJmxCommand.createJmxConnector(AbstractJmxCommand.java:279)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractJmxCommand.createJmxConnection(AbstractJmxCommand.java:302)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShutdownCommand.runTask(ShutdownCommand.java:81)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jmxrmi
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:140)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:204)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:415)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1928)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1895)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:287)
        ... 16 more
...............................
```

Comment: What version of JDK are you using? This is most likely safely ignored. 5.12.1 is very dated and this appears to be an outdated mechanism used to shutdown the broker.

Comment: Thanks for comment. java version is java version "1.7.0_261"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.22.1.el6_10-x86_64 u261-b02) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.261-b02, mixed mode)